# OWA signature with image

Tags: email, firefox, outlook-on-the-web, email-signature

From Outlook Web Access for Exchange 2003 how do I add an image to the signature?  I went to `owa/?ae=Options&t=Messaging` and updated the signature file as text.  There's no option for adding images, which I saw.

This doesn't seem to be an [out-of-box feature](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/293ea008-5ef9-4cc4-9721-c33273f93118/insert-images-into-owa-2010-signature?forum=exchange2010), but I'm not sure.  When I click on "options" I see:

```
Regional Settings
Messaging
Junk E-Mail
Calendar
Out of Office Assistant
Change Password
Accessibility
Mobile Devices
About
```

but don't see anything about `S/MIME` or security.  Perhaps I'm using a different version.  There's no version number readily apparent to me.